# find records in one table which doesn't exist in other given a certain date

Tags: sql

So I have 2 tables.

1. employees - primary table
2. emp_attend - child table
3. emp_id - is the primary key for employees table & foreign key for emp_attend

I want to select all the data that exists in employees but does not exist in emp_attend. I am able to do that with this query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT \n" +
                             "employees.emp_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name \n" +
                             "FROM employees \n" +
                             "LEFT JOIN emp_attend ON emp_attend.emp_id = employees.emp_id \n" +
                             "WHERE emp_attend.emp_id IS NULL";
```

Now, how can I include that it only selects the data that does not exist in employees table given a certain date from emp_attend table

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT \n" +
                             "employees.emp_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name \n" +
                             "FROM employees \n" +
                             "LEFT JOIN emp_attend ON emp_attend.emp_id = employees.emp_id \n" +
                             "WHERE emp_attend.emp_id IS NULL OR emp_attend.date != ?";
```

I tried the above query but it displays all the employees.

For example
for 1/5/2018 it shows all the employees that have not yet been listed in emp_attend table.

Hope you can help me thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `emp_attend.date` cocndition in the `LEFT JOIN` and not in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    employees.emp_id
    , employees.first_name
    , employees.last_name
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN emp_attend 
        ON emp_attend.emp_id = employees.emp_id 
             AND emp_attend.date = ?
WHERE emp_attend.emp_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Why didn't I think of this haha. This did it for me I just changed the != to = and I got the result I wanted.

`SELECT
    employees.emp_id
    , employees.first_name
    , employees.last_name
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN emp_attend 
        ON emp_attend.emp_id = employees.emp_id 
             AND emp_attend.date = ?
WHERE emp_attend.emp_id IS NULL;`

Thank you so much :) Have a great day Radu.

Comment: @Roger Yeah, my mistake. Forgot to remove the "!". Good spot.

Comment: No problem @Roger . Good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from employees emp
outer join emp_attend attend
on emp.emp_id = attend.emp_id
```